# How to Update database through stored procedure without knowing parameter names?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have a table and a stored procedure. I have to update the table using the stored procedure. At present I am using stored procedure with four parameters but in the future the parameter list might grow. How can I update the table without knowing parameters name and parameters count from Ado.Net?

Note: I don't know even single parameter name but I have to update that table by using stored procedure and Ado.net.

Comment: if your SP changes, the code to invoke your SP should change accordingly. this shouldn't be a big deal, since there should in most cases just be one method that invokes that SP, and then *that* method could be invoked from many places in your code, but those places don't need to be concerned with the paramter list.

Answer (score 0):

Use Optional Parameters in your stored procedures to accomplish this.

Here is one without parameters

```
Create Procedure MyProcedure
AS

Update Table Set Column = 0

GO
```

Here is one with parameters that cannot be ignored

```
Create Procedure MyProcedure
    @MyColumnValue INTEGER
AS

Update Table Set Column = @MyColumnValue

GO
```

Here is one with one parameter that cannot be ignored, and one that **can** be ignored. If you do not send a value for @MyColumn2Value, it will use the default value.

```
Create Procedure MyProcedure
    @MyColumn1Value INTEGER,
    @MyColumn2Value INTEGER = -3
AS

Update Table 
Set 
    Column1 = @MyColumn1Value
    Column2 = @MyColumn2Value

GO
```

Thus, if you add to your procedure in the future, and you do not want to break existing code, you can add optional parameters like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (database) function that returns table of parameter information of a given @RoutineName (Stored procedure name).

```
Create Function [dbo].[ftRoutineSchema](@RoutineName varchar(200)) returns table as return 
--declare @routineName varchar(100);select @routineName='ftBom4Excel'
SELECT   ColumnName=Case Is_Result
                                    When 'YES' then '@RC'
                                  else Parameter_Name
                            end
            ,DataType= case Data_Type
                            When  'DECIMAL' then 'Decimal('+convert(varchar,Numeric_precision)+','+Convert(varchar,Numeric_scale)+')'
                            When  'numeric' then 'Decimal('+convert(varchar,Numeric_precision)+','+Convert(varchar,Numeric_scale)+')'
                            when 'varchar' then 'Varchar('+Convert(varchar,Character_maximum_length)+')'
                            ELSE dATA_TYPE      
                          end
            ,ColumnOrder=Ordinal_Position   
            ,Direction =Case Parameter_Mode
                                when 'INOUT' then 'Out'
                                else Parameter_Mode
                            end

 FROM 
         Information_schema.Parameters  
  Where Specific_name=@ROUTINEnAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call SP without knowing of parameters name, just knowing parameters order.

For example, you have to call next sp: `"EXEC my_sp @a, @b, @c"`

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString")
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = String.Format("EXEC my_sp {0}, {1}, {2}", "a", "b", "c");
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```